# Vanilla javascript image carousel not initializing on first load

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, carousel, refresh

I have an issue with my image carousel not initializing on first load of the page, I have to refresh the page in order for it to work (it should start moving automatically and the play-pause and left-right buttons should work). Once I refresh, it works fine.

HTML:

```
<section id='container_four'>

    <section class='carousel'>

      <section class='slides'>
          <div class='slide'><img src='img/spain1.jpeg' alt=''></div>
          <div class='slide'><img src='img/spain2.jpeg' alt=''></div>
          <div class='slide'><img src='img/spain3.jpeg' alt=''></div>
          <div class='slide' id='slide-index-3'><img src='img/spain4.jpeg' alt=''></div>
          <div class='slide'><img src='img/spain5.jpeg' alt=''></div>
          <div class='slide'><img src='img/spain6.jpeg' alt=''></div>
          <div class='slide'><img src='img/spain7.jpeg' alt=''></div>
          
      </section>

      <section class='slide-controls'>
        <button class='prev-btn'><img src='img/arrow_left.png' alt='arrow left'></button>
        <button class='next-btn'><img src='img/arrow_right.png' alt='arrow right'></button>
      </section>

      <input type='image' class='pause' src='img/pause.png'>

    </section>
```

JS:

```
const carousel = document.querySelector('.carousel');
const slideGroup = document.querySelector('.slides');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next-btn');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prev-btn');
let playPause = document.querySelector('.pause');
let slide = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
let index = 3;
let intervalId;

//--------------------------------------------
// Clone images
const cloneOne = slide[0].cloneNode(true);
const cloneTwo = slide[1].cloneNode(true);
const cloneThree = slide[2].cloneNode(true);
const cloneFour = slide[3].cloneNode(true);
const cloneFive = slide[4].cloneNode(true);
const cloneSix = slide[5].cloneNode(true);
const cloneSeven = slide[6].cloneNode(true);

// Add clones to start and end of slide group
slideGroup.prepend(cloneFour, cloneFive, cloneSix, cloneSeven);
slideGroup.append(cloneOne, cloneTwo, cloneThree, cloneFour); 

slide = document.querySelectorAll('.slide'); 

// Set the slide width
const width = slide[index].clientWidth; 
slideGroup.style.transform = `translateX(${-width * index}px)`;

// Start automatic loop on page load
const startSlide = () => intervalId = setInterval(nextSlide, 2000); 
startSlide();
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    console.log('worked')
})

// When click the arrows...
// Move to next slide
function nextSlide() {
    console.log('nextslide works')
    index >= slide.length - 4 ? false : index++;
    slideGroup.style.transform = `translateX(${-width * index}px)`;
    slideGroup.style.transition = '1s'; 
}
// Move to previous slide
function prevSlide() {
    index <= 0 ? false : index--;
    slideGroup.style.transform = `translateX(${-width * index}px)`;
    slideGroup.style.transition = '1s';
}
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', nextSlide);
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', prevSlide);

cloneOne.id = 'clone1';
cloneFive.id = 'clone5';
    
function transitionEnd() {
    console.log('transitionend works')
    if(slide[index].id === 'clone1') {
        slideGroup.style.transition = 'ease-in';
        index = 3;
        slideGroup.style.transform = `translateX(${-width * index}px)`; 
    }
    if(slide[index].id === 'clone5') {
        slideGroup.style.transition = 'none';
         index = 7;
        slideGroup.style.transform = `translateX(${-width * index}px)`;
    }
}
slideGroup.addEventListener('transitionend', transitionEnd); 

// When press play/pause button, start/stop and change icon
function playOrPause() {
    console.log('playpause works')
    if(!intervalId) {
        playPause.src = 'img/pause.png';
        return startSlide(); 
    } else {
        playPause.src = 'img/play.png';
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        intervalId = null;
    }
}
playPause.addEventListener('click', playOrPause)

// Play/pause button mouseover event
playPause.addEventListener('mouseout', () => playPause.style.opacity = '0');
playPause.addEventListener('mouseover', () => playPause.style.opacity = '1');

// Keyboard function
function onKeydown(e) {
    switch(e.key) {
        case 'ArrowLeft':
            prevSlide();
            break;
        case 'ArrowRight':
            nextSlide();
            break;
        case 32:
            e.preventDefault();
            playOrPause();
    }
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeydown);
```

CSS:

```
#container_four {
  background-color: #DED6D3;
  padding: 5% 0%;
}
.carousel {
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.slides {
  display: flex; 
} 
.slide {
  min-width: 25%;
}
.slide img {
  width: 80%; 
}
.slide-controls {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 0;
}
.slide-controls img {
  width: 2vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.next-btn,
.prev-btn {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 2vw;
}
.next-btn:focus,
.prev-btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.play, 
.pause {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 4vw;
  outline: none;
  padding: 15% 25%;
}
```

I added console logs in each function and have discovered that the `transitionend` event listener does not fire. I have even tried rewriting it in different ways. The only thing that makes it fire is if I refresh the browser!

Any suggestions of what the problem might be? I am confused why the transitionend event is blocked on first load, but then is accessible after refresh... the other event listeners look to be working on first load.

To be clear, this problem only occurs on the very first load of the page, so revisiting the page will work correctly. It's only when you open a new browser with no history of the website that it doesn't work.

Here is the page: https://chunzg.github.io/carousel/
Github link to the code: https://github.com/chunzg/carousel

Comment: Are you waiting for all the images to load before, for example, you try to look at their width?

Comment: Sorry not sure I understand your comment? But now I noticed another problem, sometimes when I refresh, it also doesn't work :/ So basically sometimes it works and sometimes not. On mobile it hardly ever works, no matter the browser...

Comment: don't post a link to the code, paste the actual code into this question

Comment: What I meant was, does your code wait for, say, the window load event before it tries to use e.g. imgs? Please put enough code in your question that shows the problem so we can help more.

Comment: I have added my code into the question itself. I thought that the window load event happens automatically once you go onto the url, but it looks like it is not explicitly doing that since it does not move the first time. I think there may be an issue with the `transitionend` listener